# An example of transferring the C ++ class hierarchy to Golang. Is it done correctly?

Tags: c++, object-oriented, comparative-review, go

I am trying to transfer my c ++ experience to the Go area. I'm new to Go, so not sure if the implementation is correct. In any case, it looks very ugly compared to C ++ code. Is there a nicer solution? Both solutions are executable in playground and give same result.

c++ playground: https://code.sololearn.com/c67xbW2AEWW2/#cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Abstract class
class AbstractGenerator
{
public:
    AbstractGenerator() {}
    std::string generate(std::string some_internal_data)
    {
        _some_internal_data = some_internal_data;
        return step1() + step2();
    }

protected:
    // some shared fuctions
    std::string generationHelper1(std::string s) { return s + _some_internal_data + "123"; }
    std::string generationHelper2(std::string s) { return s + _some_internal_data + "456"; }
    // abstract fucntions
    virtual std::string step1() = 0;
    virtual std::string step2() = 0;

private:
    std::string _some_internal_data;
};
// Implementation
class MyGenerator : public AbstractGenerator
{
public:
    MyGenerator() {}

protected:
    std::string step1() override { return generationHelper1("my step1") + generationHelper2("my step1"); }
    std::string step2() override { return "my step2"; }
};

int main() {
    MyGenerator my_gen;
    AbstractGenerator* abstract_gen = &my_gen;
    cout << abstract_gen->generate("data");
    return 0;
}
```

Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/e3iXfYar4YJ

```
package main

import "fmt"

// some shared fuctions - interface
type ImplementationHelper interface {
    generationHelper1(s string) string
    generationHelper2(s string) string
}

// abstract fucntions - interface
type Implementation interface {
    step1() string
    step2() string
}

// Public main interface
type Generator interface {
    Generate(s string) string
}

type AbstractGenerator struct {
    someInternalData string
    implementation   Implementation
}

func NewAbstractGenerator(i Implementation) *AbstractGenerator {
    g := new(AbstractGenerator)
    g.implementation = i
    return g
}
func (g *AbstractGenerator) Generate(s string) string {
    g.someInternalData = s
    return g.implementation.step1() + g.implementation.step2()
}
func (g *AbstractGenerator) generationHelper1(s string) string { return s + g.someInternalData + "123" }
func (g *AbstractGenerator) generationHelper2(s string) string { return s + g.someInternalData + "456" }

// Implementation of AbstractGenerator
type MyGenerator struct {
    basic *AbstractGenerator
}

// MyGenerator constructor
func NewMyGenerator() *MyGenerator {
    myGen := new(MyGenerator)
    myGen.basic = NewAbstractGenerator(myGen)
    return myGen
}

// Interface Generator
func (i *MyGenerator) Generate(s string) string {
    return i.basic.Generate(s)
}

// Interface Implementation
func (i *MyGenerator) step1() string {
    return i.basic.generationHelper1("my step1") + i.basic.generationHelper2("my step1")
}
func (i *MyGenerator) step2() string {
    return "my step2"
}

func main() {
    myGen := NewMyGenerator()

    var abstractGen Generator
    abstractGen = myGen

    fmt.Println(abstractGen.Generate("data"))
}
```

Comment: yeah, this code sucks. Whats does it try to achieve ? Thinking about it, i just dont see the point in abstracting anything in  *this example*. I would just have two concrete implementations, and if i need to communicate instances to a third party, let it declare a private interface to receive this or that implementation....

Comment: the constructor `NewMyGenerator` is really funny. It creates a `MyGenerator` that is given to an `AbstractGenerator` that in turn is registered as a delegate to `MyGenerator`. That is not good. This complexity is unjustified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand OP code goals, it floats in thin air.

But i would simply not abstract anything unless required.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type GeneratorA struct {
}

func (g GeneratorA) Generate(data string) string {
    return "generator A"
}

type GeneratorB struct {
}

func (g GeneratorB) Generate(data string) string {
    return "generator B"
}

func main() {
    consumeGenerator(GeneratorA{})
    consumeGenerator(GeneratorB{})
}

func consumeGenerator(g interface{ Generate(string) string }) {
    fmt.Println(g.Generate("whatever"))
}
```

anyways, reproducing OOP in a language that promotes composition is just not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```golang
g := new(AbstractGenerator)
g.implementation = i
return g
```

Can be more simply written as:

```golang
return &AbstractGenerator{implementation: i}
```